# Querying DynamoDB inside a Docker Container is returning limiting results

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, amazon-dynamodb

When I query DynamoDB from inside a Linux Docker container, the consumed capacity is much lower then when I run the same query on my host windows machine. [image: image showing results of query inside and outside of container] Here I am printing out the results of the query. On the left is inside the docker container, and on the right is on my windows machine (both queries are using the same aws user).

The container is running golang:1.9 image.

I noticed this first in the golang aws/sdk package and opened an issue with them [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1695), but after I installed the aws cli in the container and got the same results I realized it wasn't a sdk issue.

I have only tested this with the golang:1.9 image.

Any ideas for trouble shooting this or suggestions?

Comment: Also I don't know if it's related, but the table currently has 27 items, I can scan it from windows and it shows it a ScannedCount of 27, expected. But when I scan from the Docker container, it shows 88...

Comment: Could be any number of things, but here's one to start with. Which region are you defaulting to on each environment? For cli this is usually set in your AWS cred store, for the sdk I guess you initialising your connection with a region. Could you have two tables with the same name in different regions?

Comment: I don't think so, when I use the cli between the host and the container i specify the same region. For my aws creds I don't specify the region. Just my login info. Is the region stored in those? If I remember you have to specify the region manually in the cred file don't you?

Comment: Could you post your CLI and golang queries, as well as the full result outcomes (not the actual results)? Please use text rather than screenshots as this is discouraged on SO.